# How can I permanently change the color of an item in a ListView?

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, common-controls

I have create list a listview

```
list[0]=CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW,L"",WS_DLGFRAME|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LVS_REPORT|LVS_SINGLESEL,-,-,-,-,hwnd,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
LVCOLUMN lvcolumn;
lvcolumn.mask = LVCF_FMT|LVCF_TEXT|LVCF_WIDTH;
lvcolumn.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;
lvcolumn.pszText = L"a";
lvcolumn.cx = 100;
ListView_InsertColumn(list[0],0,&lvcolumn);
lvcolumn.pszText = L"b";
ListView_InsertColumn(list[0],1,&lvcolumn);
lvcolumn.pszText = L"c";
ListView_InsertColumn(list[0],2,&lvcolumn);
lvcolumn.pszText = L"d";
ListView_InsertColumn(list[0],3,&lvcolumn);
```

And I use LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW to insert color item

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    if( ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW){
        switch( ((LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam)->nmcd.dwDrawStage){
            case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                break;
            case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            {
                LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW customDraw = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;

                customDraw->clrText = getcolor();
                return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                break;
            }
            default: return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        }
    }
    break;
```

getcolor is function response colorref. Each item have it own text color. But when the parent window is hide and show again the item color is change. So how to keep it not change or we have another way to set text color

One more I create an new listview item by this way (in case someone need it)

```
ListView_InsertItem(hwndlist,&lvitem);
ListView_SetItemText(hwndlist,i,k,(LPWSTR)strarr[k].c_str());
```

Comment: getcolor() has no arguments.  So it can't generate a consistent color for an item.  You'll need to at least pass dwItemSpec

Comment: The only way to set the colour is to respond to the custom draw messages. There is no other concept of "permanant colour". As @Hans says, you need to give it the correct colour when it asks.

Comment: Well I try to gettext of the text in get color. I got listitem Id. But I don't know how to get subitem id(the column).